# Custom Plymouth splash isn't showing up

Tags: plymouth

I'm having trouble with my custom Plymouth theme. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and the X11 Plymouth plugin (so I don't have to restart the computer). But when I run the plugin all I get is a black screen, my splash image doesn't show up. My .plymouth file:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=Cornflower
Description=Cornflower plymouth theme
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/lib/plymouth/themes/cornflower
ScriptFile=/lib/plymouth/themes/cornflower/cornflower.script
```

My .script file:

```
flower_image = Image(Untitled.png);
flower_sprite = Sprite(flower_image);
flower_sprite.SetX(Window.GetWidth()/2 - flower_image.GetWidth()/2);
flower_sprite.SetY(Window.GetHeight()/2 - flower_image.GetHeight()/2);
progress = 0;
fun refresh_callback ()
  {
   progress++;
   flower_sprite.rotate(progress);
  }
```

If any more information is needed I will provide it.

Edit: and for the record, I did try the framebuffer=y technique but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this?